# How to Implement Retry analyzer in try catch Block?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Below is my code after got the exception immediately it should trigger one more time for execution but didn't execute.Without try,catch it was executing but after keep the code in try and catch RetryAnalyzer is not working as expected please anyone help me how to implement RetryAnalyzer in try,catch block

```
@Test(priority=4,enabled=true,retryAnalyzer=RetryAnalyzer.class)
public void TC_04() throws InterruptedException
{
    try
    {
    extent=new 
    ExtentReports("/Users/anakin/workspace/Reports/MKE.html");
    Login_Objects.Switch_PB2U(driver).click();
    String screenshot_path = Screenshot.createScreenshot(driver);
    String image = log.addScreenCapture(screenshot_path);
    log.log(LogStatus.PASS, "To Stocks",image);
    extent.endTest(log);
    driver.closeApp();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    String screenshot_path = Screenshot.createScreenshot(driver);
    String image = log.addScreenCapture(screenshot_path);
    log.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Verify Suggest Stocks ", image);
    extent.endTest(log);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Catching exception in your complete test code is a bad practice. Even as in your case you are capturing screenshot in case of failure, **`you should use listener than catching exception.`**

Since retry analyzer works for failed tests, and you are cathing exceptions and thus supressing the errors, it might give the impression that your test never failed and thus the retryAnalyzer is not working.

**Solution** : **`Move code in Exception to Listeners and remove unnecessary Exception handling.`**

Comment: Hi Abhishek thanks for your information could you please elaborate your answer how to implement listeners instead of try/catch block

Comment: There are many tutorials available on line. Try them yourself, let us know if you face any issue. Example Tutorial : https://www.swtestacademy.com/how-to-use-testng-listeners/